# Fiberwise injective resolution of coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, coherent-sheaves, flatness, injective-modules

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field (of characteristic zero) and $X, Y$ be projective $k$-varieties. Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X \times_k Y$, flat over $Y$. Does there exists a coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X \times Y}$-module, say $G$ on $X \times Y$ flat over $Y$ containing $F$ such that for each $y \in Y$,

1) $G|_{X_y}$ is injective and

2) $F|_{X_y} \subset G|_{X_y}$, where $X_y:=X \times \{y\}$?

Any reference/hint will be most welcome.

Comment: You certainly cannot arrange the last two conditions that $I|_{X_y}$ is injective and $F|_{X_y}\to I|_{X_y}$ is injective.  Consider the case that $X$ equals $\text{Spec}\ k = \text{Proj}\ k[t]$ and $Y$ is $\mathbb{P}^1 = \text{Proj}\ k[u,v]$.  Let $F$ be the structure sheaf.  Since every injective sheaf is divisible, $I|_{X_y}$ is a zero sheaf.  Yet $F|_{X_y}$ is the structure sheaf of $X_y$.

Comment: @JasonStarr I have modified the question. I no longer assume that the sheaf over $X \times Y$ is injective. Is this now possible or is it false as well?

Comment: If $G$ is coherent, then $G|_{X_y}$ is also coherent.  For $X_y$ equal to $\mathbb{P}^1_{\kappa(y)}$, for instance, the only coherent sheaf that is also injective is the zero sheaf.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. One last question. Is the question still wrong if instead of coherent, I ask for quasi-coherent (at all places)?

Comment: "... I ask for quasi-coherent (at all places)?"  You could take a direct sum over all points $y$ of $Y$ of the pushforward from $X_y$ of an injective quasi-coherent sheaf that contains $F|_{X_y}$.